# iOS Google Maps SDK new icon View animations

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, ios-animations

According to the documentation regarding the GMSMarker new property iconView:

> The view behaves as if clipsToBounds is set to YES, regardless of its actual value

So there is no way of changing that clipsToBounds to NO? How are animations supposed to work if they go outside the view bounds?

[Animation Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhc9zb7r5m6ipeb/mapAnimation.mov?dl=0)

```
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.title = "Stop 1"
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
    marker.map = mapView

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "markerIcon"))
    marker.iconView = imageView

    let pulseEffect = LFTPulseAnimation(repeatCount: Float.infinity, radius:45, position:imageView.center)
    marker.iconView.layer.insertSublayer(pulseEffect, below: imageView.layer)
```

Comment: same issue , are you able to find solution for this ?